# Pyspark issue with json having a field with string as well as array values

Tags: json, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a Spark cluster and have to index JSON data to Elastic Search (ES). There is a column as follows (two samples only):

```
"ADDRESS": "PO box 1234, Lahore"
"ADDRESS": [ "PO box 5678, Karachi", "new city Lahore"]
```

The problem with above column is that, in some records, it is appearing as string and in some other cases, it is appearing as array of string. I have tested above case in ES, there is no issue in ES, it can index both cases without issue (if directly indexed).

I have written a Spark (pyspark) job to read large JSON and then insert it to ES. In Spark schema, it is showing this field as string instead of array. Now, when I insert data into ES, I get following responses

```
"ADDRESS": "PO box 1234, Lahore",
"ADDRESS": "[\"PO box 5678, Karachi\", \"new city Lahore\"]",
```

Instead of showing as array data, it is showing as string. Now, where is the issue ? I am reading JSON as follows:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "false").json(data_path)
```

**Updated**
Sample Input data as seen in dataframe
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your expectation? do you want your dataframe `df` to have that column as String or Array?

Comment: I want all data as array of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is turning **string** `"PO box 1234, Lahore"` into **string** `["PO box 1234, Lahore"]`, then convert all of them into Array of String, like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('ADDRESS2', F
        .when(~F.col('ADDRESS').startswith('['), F.concat(F.lit('["'), F.col('ADDRESS'), F.lit('"]')))
        .otherwise(F.col('ADDRESS'))
    )
    .withColumn('ADDRESS2', F.from_json('ADDRESS2', T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
    .show(10, False)
)

# Output
# +------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
# |ADDRESS                                   |ADDRESS2                               |
# +------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
# |PO box 1234, Lahore                       |[PO box 1234, Lahore]                  |
# |["PO box 5678, Karachi","new city Lahore"]|[PO box 5678, Karachi, new city Lahore]|
# +------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+


# root
#  |-- ADDRESS: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- ADDRESS2: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to do it on values only. Input string is just values in data-frame

Comment: hm I don’t get that? can you share a bit more?

Comment: Yes, let me to update the question

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Thanks, the input you shown is what I expected too. If you see the code I posted, it reading from your original input which is string (`ADDRESS` column). Then I create a new column (not necessarily, you can override `ADDRESS` column if you want) called `ADDRESS2`, and after the transformation, you can see the schema at the bottom saying `ADDRESS2` is Array of String